IIS 10: is there a way to disable the app-pool-autofill when adding a website?
When I add a website in IIS 10, whatever I type into the sitename field also automatically fills the app-pool field, which I then have to manually change to the app-pool I actually want to use.
--> screenshot <--
Even if I set my desired app-pool as default, this still happens. Is there any way to turn off that autofill feature, so that it always selects my default app-pool?

That’s very much a feature of IIS Manager. BTW, if you feel the needs to change that behaviour, you might consider creating sites using PowerShell scripts where you have more control.
